# ASP.NET MVC ajax - data transfer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax

How can I get result from action?
I need to show the **commentID** on the page (aspx) **after successes** comment insert.

controller

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post )]
        public ActionResult ShowArticleByAjax(Guid id, string commentBody)
        {

            Guid commentID = Comment.InsertComment(id, commentBody);

            //How can I tranfer  commentID to the  aspx page ???                 
            return PartialView("CommentDetails",Article.GetArticleByID(id));
          }
```

ascx

```
<%using (Ajax.BeginForm("ShowArticleByAjax", new {  id = Model.ID },
               new AjaxOptions { 
                                                HttpMethod = "Post",
                                                UpdateTargetId = "divCommentDetails",
                                                OnSuccess = "successAddComment",
                                                OnFailure = "failureAddComment",
                                                OnBegin = "beginAddComment"
               })) 
          { %>


        <p>
            <%=Html.TextArea("commentBody", new { cols = "100%", rows = "10" })%>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input name="submit" type="image" src="../../Content/Images/Design/button_s.gif"
                id="submit" />
        </p>

        <%} %>
```

aspx

```
  doesn't matter
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the this:

```
ViewData["ID"] = commentID;
```

and then print it with:

```
<%= ViewData["ID"]%>
```

Comment: It's right, but i forgot to say I need to check into the aspx page(!!!)  is this ajaxRequest. It's impossible, right?

Comment: the setting part is in your controller and the other part "<%= ViewData["ID"]%>" is in your aspx page

Comment: For example, please. Show the aspx and controller. I'm not sure it will be work success.

Comment: please post all the code for your "CommentDetails"view. Is it strongly typed?